# What is the WPF equivalant of DocumentCompleted?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I checked.  This question has not been asked yet.  What is the WPF equivalant of DocumentCompleted for the WebBrowser class?

the DocumentCompleted method does not exist in WPF (at least not in the latest version of .NET and visual studio).  So how do I do the same thing that one could do with Windows Forms in WPF?

Comment: Never skipping an opportunity to make Winforms programmers feel lost, they called it LoadCompleted.

Answer (score 6):

The event that you are looking for is LoadCompleted.

Your can read more about it in .NET docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.90).aspx