# WebBrowser control from Console app using F#

Tags: wpf, f#

I have a .netcoreapp3.1 Console App

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In Program.fs, I am instantiating a WebBrowser control and handling the DocumentCompleted event

```
let run() =
    let uri = "https://www.microsoft.com"
    let browser = new WebBrowser()
    browser.DocumentCompleted.Add(fun _ -> handlePage browser uris)
    browser.Navigate(uri)

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    run()
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

When I run it, the DocumentCompleted event is never fired or handled - the program runs through to the end.

Am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing?

The message pump. You need a `Dispatcher` to run a WPF app.

On another note, you're using the WinForms `WebBrowser`, that one exposes the `DocumentCompleted` event. The WPF variant has the `LoadCompleted` event, ref this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078331/what-is-the-wpf-equivalant-of-documentcompleted).

In WPF, however, the concept of `Loaded` is related to the visual tree. As you're not rendering the control, the event will never be raised. If we instead use the `Navigated` event, we can get there with minimal fuss.

```ml
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

type BrowserApplication() =
   inherit Application()

   let run() =
       let uri = "https://www.microsoft.com"
       let browser = new WebBrowser()
       browser.Navigated.Add(fun _ -> Console.WriteLine("Done navigating"))
       browser.Navigate(uri)

   do run();

[<EntryPoint;STAThread>]  
let main argv =   
    BrowserApplication().Run()
```